# Bootstrap 3 100% height cell

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have very simple row with two columns, each with list.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row list-row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 list-container">
      <div class="well  list-container">
         <ul>
            <li>Foo</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 list-container">
      <div class="well list-container">
         <ul>
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Foo</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I want is to make each well and list same height, no matter how much items is in each of them (I'll use them to drag and drop from one to another). I was able to achieve it partially with following css.

```
.list-row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-container {
  margin-bottom: -9999px;
  padding-bottom: 9999px;
}
```

But wells are cropped in the bottom (ugly!) and no matter what I do, lists are only as big as much elements they got.

Comment: Pretty sure you can use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for this

Comment: that breaks bootstrap badly, tried that.

Answer (score 0):

give list-container class a min-width property. If you know how many items will be in there, give min-width a maximum number. For example:

You have max 5 li element in your ul and each ones height is 10px give list-container class a min-width: 50px

Comment: I know how to set min-height, of course. it is done that way at the moment, but I'd like to just make two cells same width.